# A-camera kynematic-body can not move closely to static-body?

Tags: distance, aframe, physics-engine, 3d-model

First of all, I'm sorry about not inlining images because of lacking reputation.

I have 2 problems with `Aframe-extras` by DonMcCurdy and I've read many documents but could not find the solution.

FYI, I've set `kinematic-body` for my `camera`.

**Problem 1:**

I can not go inside my `static-body` *circular table*:

My circular table:
[image: My circular table]

The table was made with `Blender` and was exported to `Collada model`.

I know that `aframe-extras` will consider my circular as a box (bounding box of the model) and it prevent me to move through that box. That's why I cannot come inside my *circular table*.

So that I'm going to use the solution 2,
I remove the `static-body` from my circular table, then create a `static-body` "line" around the circular table myself.
But I met the problem 2 below:

**Problem 2:**

The `static-body` bar (It's the red one in below image) prevent me to move closer to it, the minimum distance from me to the red bar **~1.5 unit** * (1 unit = 1 meter in my case)*.

My expectation distance is **20cm**.

So the final question is:

**How can I move closer to it?**

You can see my screenshot here:
[image: my screenshot here] for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I looked the default radius to the kinematic-body was 1.3, that looks like it's too wide for your scene. Try setting the radius to 0.5.

```
kinematic-body="radius:0.5"
```

If that doesn't work, you may also need to check the static body and set the shape to hull.

```
static-body="shape:hull"
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that `kinematic-body="radius:0.5"` really work great for a wall, but my bar is not enough height to make it work. 
I will try to make my bar become a wall.
Can you tell me how will `static-body="shape:hull"` behavior?

Comment: FYI, This is video when I set `kinematic-body="radius:0.5"` for my camera, and `static-body="shape:hull" ` for the red box.
     
https://photos.app.goo.gl/tukxoyV2dtVPkNUX2.
      
`<Entity camera="userHeight: 2; fov: 80;"  kinematic-body="radius:0.5" ... />`
`<a-box static-body="shape:hull" color="tomato" depth="0.1" height="1" width="20" position="0 1.0 -4" material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.9"/>`

Comment: As I understand it the hull shape is a mesh that will try to conform to the shape of a simple model. Complex models my not necessarily work. Set physics="debug: true" to check that the static-body has applied to the model.

Comment: You don't need to set the shape to hull for a box entity. Hull should only be necessary for models. The default static-body should be adequate.

Comment: Yes static-body was applied to the red bar. But to prevent player can go through the red bar, I need to make red bar more height:
From: `<a-box static-body="shape: box;" color="tomato" height="1" width="20" ...`
.....  To: `<a-box static-body="shape: box;" color="tomato" height="2" width="20"...`.

Comment: Anw, `kinematic-body="radius:0.5"` is the answer. But I need to make the wall - sth biger instead of the small box or the line to prevent user go through it. Thanks, you're hero :D. Where is the document about the `radius`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who met the same problem, my solution is:

- As @manny-meadows suggest: Set `radius` to `0.5` (0.2 = 20cm is too small)

  > `kinematic-body="radius:0.5"`
- Then you still go through the red bar, like this video:  [photos.app.goo.gl/tukxoyV2dtVPkNUX2](http://%20photos.app.goo.gl/tukxoyV2dtVPkNUX2)
  So need to do an extra thing, increase your bar height:

  From:

  > < a-box static-body="shape: box;" color="tomato" depth="0.1" `height="1"` width="20" position="0 0 -4" material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.9"/>`

  To:

  > < a-box static-body="shape: box;" color="tomato" depth="0.1" `height="2"` width="20" position="0 0 -4" material="transparent: true; opacity: 0.9"/>

Everything work.